# No view duplicate from work

Tags: php, mysql

How to prevent duplicate records from my table:

```
<select name="web_site">
     <?php
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `work`");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            print '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please elaborate your question in detail

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `work` group by title");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="web_site">
     <?php
        $query = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT title FROM `work`");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            print '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```